# Retrieve XDocument Immediate Node Value linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response version="1.0">
    <respcode>200</respcode>
    <respmessage>Success</respmessage>
    <datetime>Thu, 18 Jan 2018 06:20:25 +0000</datetime>
    <location>
        <site_code>COH</site_code>
        <phone>781-383-0180</phone>
        <fax>781-383-9093</fax>
        <standardized_operation_hours>
            <Monday>07:30-17:00</Monday>
            <Tuesday>07:30-17:00</Tuesday>
            <Wednesday>07:30-17:00</Wednesday>
            <Thursday>07:30-17:00</Thursday>
            <Friday>07:30-17:00</Friday>
            <Saturday>X</Saturday>
            <Sunday>X</Sunday>
    </standardized_operation_hours>
    <scheduling>YES</scheduling>
    <time_zone>America/New_York</time_zone>
    </location>
</response>
```

Here is my code to parse and retrieve values of the child elements:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"F:\Appointment Scheduling
  Info\CompleteFacilities.xml");

var locations = from location in document.Descendants("location")
                select new
                {
                    siteCode = location.Element("site_code").Value,
                    phone = location.Element("phone").Value,
                    fax = location.Element("fax").Value,
                    standardized_operation_hours = location.Element("standardized_operation_hours"),
                    timeZone = location.Element("time_zone") != null ? location.Element("time_zone").Value : null,
                    scheduling = location.Element("scheduling") != null ? location.Element("scheduling").Value : null                                
                };
```

Question:
I can retrieve the PhoneNUmber using: locations.First().phone

But when I access, locations.First().standardized_operation_hours.Value - I was expecting to get the child node value:

```
<Monday>07:30-17:00</Monday>
<Tuesday>07:30-17:00</Tuesday>
<Wednesday>07:30-17:00</Wednesday>
<Thursday>07:30-17:00</Thursday>
<Friday>07:30-17:00</Friday>
<Saturday>X</Saturday>
<Sunday>X</Sunday>`
```

What is retrieved is the leaf value: "07:30-17:0007:30-17:0007:30-17:0007:30-17:0007:30-17:00XX"

How do I retrieve the above expected value with complete child node info containing Monday / Tuesday..?

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/yX6xDx which shows that `locations.First().standardized_operation_hours` is what you expect.  But why the additional `.Value`?

Comment: Maybe you want `locations.First().standardized_operation_hours.Elements().ToList()`?

Comment: Try following : standardized_operation_hours = location.Element("standardized_operation_hours").Elements().Select(x => new {day = x.Name.LocalName, time = (string)x}).ToArray()

Comment: Thanks @dbc. This is what I was looking for